# Access custom xml value on override method in a extended class

Tags: java, android, xml

I extend the Button class, in this class, I override the method
**setCompoundDrawables** to shrink the drawable to the button size. I set a custom value for XML element and I need to access it to calculate the size I will give to the drawable. I do the typical stuff with typedarray to retrieve the value, just after the super call in the constructor, but when the app call **setCompoundDrawables** the app has not read the custom XML values yet, so I get always the same (default) value to my custom variable.

Some code:

```
public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.context = context;
    init(attrs);
}


public void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    myValue = true;
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.MyButton,
                0, 0);
        try {
            myValue = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyButton_myValue, true);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "myValue (init) = "+myValue);
}

@Override
public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
    Log.d(TAG, "myValue (setComp...) = "+myValue);
    ...
    super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

when I run my app I get the printings in this order:

```
myValue (setComp...) = false
myValue (init) = true
```

Can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: I solve this doing this: Drawable[] d = getCompoundDrawables(); setCompoundDrawables(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]); at the end of init method and it works, but I think it is not the way to do this...